# MySQL Stored Procedure Select Check Insert

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, sql-insert

So I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL version 5.5. 
I'm not sure what is wrong but what I want to accomplish is.

Get record From Table-A that over 7 days old. And then insert into Table-B, but I need to check if it is exist in Table B. If it is exists then skip, else Insert it.

So here is my code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `move_record`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `move_record`()
BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE dt DATETIME;
        DECLARE uid,value BIGINT(20);
        DECLARE category VARCHAR(30);
        DECLARE data,comments VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE cancel TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL;

        DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT `datetime`,user_id,category,data,comments,cancel FROM `record` WHERE `datetime` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

        OPEN curs;

        myloop: LOOP
        FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO dt,uid,category,data,comments,cancel;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE myloop;
        END IF;

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `record_arc`
                        WHERE record_arc.`datetime` = dt
                        AND record.user_id = uid )
        INSERT INTO `record_arc` (`datetime`,user_id,category,data,comments,cancel) VALUES (dt,uid,category,data,comments,cancel);

        END IF;
        END LOOP myloop;

        CLOSE curs;
        DEALLOCATE curs;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: LEAVE read_loop????? it should be "LEAVE myloop"

Comment: Please let us know the error which you are getting.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `record_arc` (`datetime`,user_id,category,data,comments,cancel) VALU' at line 25

Comment: "record_arc.user_id". [your code has record.user_id.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do this without a loop.

```
INSERT INTO `record_arc`(
    `datetime`,
    user_id,
    category,
    data,
    comments,
    cancel
)
SELECT 
    `datetime`,
    user_id,
    category,
    data,
    comments,
    cancel 
FROM `record` r
WHERE 
    `datetime` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM `record_arc` r2
        WHERE
            r2.`datetime` = r.`datetime`
            AND r2.user_id = r.user_id
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. Btw If I have many records, will it affect performance? ex. I have 100 thousands rows for each execution, or maybe more rows

Comment: This will be faster than the loop implementation. Generally a set-based approach should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Alias name you used it wrongly. Check the below code

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `record_arc`
                            WHERE record_arc.`datetime` = dt
                            AND record_arc.user_id = uid )
```